# Unexpected changes in reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

So there's someone today who decided to pump me up to ten thousands (said with Vegeta voice) hunting my questions and +1 them. 
Now I went back to 9664... fact is that when I started today I was beyond 9800 (otherwise I would have hit the cap limit for the day, and never reached 10k). So my assumption is that he removed the +1 to my questions, and also others he voted in the past (and he unlocked, probably by editing them).

The fact (bug? lacking feature? planned feature?) is that I don't see in the daily report any -10 for the removed points. This is kind of expected (if you +1 someone and then remove the +1, he does not see +10 followed by -10. The +10 just disappears) but because in general the +1 is removed and added within the same day. If this happens much later, the points disappear from the grand total, but you have no clue where they were removed from.

I mark it as bug, but it's probably by design, and in any case a minor annoyance, like the "where the badge comes from" case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's more likely that the [vote fraud detector](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) spotted the bad upvotes and just removed them. It may have happened for more than one day, hence losing more rep.

It's annoying - particularly as it can interact badly with the rep cap in some situations - but it's best to shrug your shoulders and move on.

Comment: ohhh that's cool :)

Comment: Sounds like it may have also triggered a rep recalculation.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get bumped back down when you crossed the 100,00 mark Jon.  A lot of people were trying to push you over.